# How do I use a gazetteer with Tokensregex?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have successfully been able to use tokensregex for rule-based named entity recognition but want to increase the accuracy by adding gazetteers as an additional layer.

My data is not actually in a file but in a map that looks like: 
{"China" =["shanghai","Beijing","Gonzo,"....], "United Kingdom" = ["London", "Manchester","Edinburgh",...]} where the key is the country name and value is the corresponding cities.

1. Can I use this format i.e a map or do I need to have a tsv file with location name and the LOCATION tag?
2. How do I use the Gazetteer annotation with tokensregex?
3. Also since tokesnregex looks at one token at a time how do I match multi token words like New York in the gazetteer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the `regexner` annotator as a first layer to perform dictionary based look up.  This allows for tagging sequences of tokens with a particular NER tag using a dictionary.

Documentation here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html